# Session.GetOperationState() method is throwing exception "Method C_GetOperationState returned CKR_FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED in SoftHSM"

Tags: c#, pkcs#11, ecdsa, pkcs11interop, softhsm

We are using **SoftHSM** in our application. We have generated tokens and imported keys in it. Now we have created one job which monitors if our SoftHSM is Up and running.

For that, It seems that the Session.GetOperationState() method should be able to work. However I am getting an error message as below:

Method C_GetOperationState returned CKR_FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED.

Please help, if this method is suitable for my need or should I usew some other function.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `Session::GetOperationState` freezes cryptographic operation (e.g. after computation of hash for the first half of file) and method `Session::SetOperationState` resumes cryptographic operation (e.g. for the computation of hash for the second half of the file).

If you want to perform health check of your HSM it should be enough to open new session with `Slot::OpenSession` method, check its state with `Session::GetSessionInfo` method and close the session afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Jariq. So this is what I am using now:
`if(session.GetSessionInfo().State.Equals(CKS.CKS_RO_PUBLIC_SESSION))`
And I have not provided any token name and passphrase yet.